# Streaming video using fork does not return content

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, video-streaming, fork

I've experienced some sort of timeout when I try to request the same video stream twice, therefor I thought a fork could solve my problem.

Before I start, I'm using a [third party class for video streams](https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293). Using my own routing system this works, but I have the problem stated above.

```
public function stream ($req, $res) {
    $video = c_video_folder . $req->get_param('id') . '.mp4';

    if (file_exists($video)) {
        $res->videoStream($video);
    } else {
        $res->failure(204); // no content
    }
}
```

After trying to use a fork, it looks like this:

```
public function stream ($req, $res) {
    $video = c_video_folder . $req->get_param('id') . '.mp4';

    if (file_exists($video)) {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1) {
            $res->videoStream($video);
        } else { //async
            $res->videoStream($video);
        }
    } else {
        $res->failure(204); // no content
    }
}
```

The problem that occur is the response package contains no data, except the correct headers and such. Does anyone know why this happens?

PS. the parameter $res, is simply another class setting headers and then calling the VideoStream class linked in the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to start using forks and pthreads to handle this, even if I did it wouldn't solved my problem.

What happens is when i try to refresh the page, it won't let me until the buffering is done.

So how do I stop buffering in html5 video tag?
It's simple, you have to pause the video, and the buffering will stop making you able to refresh the page.

It's also important to stop the buffer even before you've started the video to avoid further problems (such as the video won't load next time, unfortunately I don't know why this happens). Using Angular.js I solved this by listened to a page refresh, set the volume to 0 (to mute sounds when you play it), started the video and paused it.
It works perfectly, and here's how I did it:

```
angular.element($window).on('beforeunload', function (event) {
        vp.volume = 0;
        vp.play();
        vp.pause();
    });
```